# Why VQE don't work?

Tags: pennylane

I try to make VQE optimizer, but something goes wrong at the optimization stage, more precisely, the parameters do not change and there is no gradient descent. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
import pennylane as qml

from pennylane import qaoa
from pennylane import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

numer_stability_const = 0.1
op_new = sparse.csr_matrix(op)
ham =  qml.SparseHamiltonian(op_new * numer_stability_const, wires=list(range(16)))
size = len(ham.wires)
dev = qml.device("default.qubit", wires=size)
def  circuit(params):

    for i in range(size):
        qml.RY(params[0][i][0], wires=i)
        qml.RZ(params[0][i][1], wires=i)

    for i in range(size - 1):
        qml.CZ(wires=[i, i + 1])
def layer(params):
    for i in range(size):
        qml.RY(params[i][0], wires=i)
        qml.RZ(params[i][1], wires=i)

    for i in range(size - 1):
        qml.CZ(wires=[i, i + 1])
device = qml.device("default.qubit", wires=size)
num_layers = 3

@qml.qnode(device, diff_method="parameter-shift")
def feed_forward(params, wires=size):
    for k in range(3):
        layer(params[k])

    for i in range(size):
        qml.RY(params[-1][i][0], wires=i)
        qml.RZ(params[-1][i][1], wires=i)
    
    return qml.expval(ham)
opt = qml.MomentumOptimizer()
params = tuple(
    tuple(
    (
        np.random.rand() * 2 * np.pi,
        np.random.rand() * 2 * np.pi,
    )
    for _ in range(size)
)
for _ in range(num_layers + 1)
)
energy = [
feed_forward(params),
]

for epoch in range(25):
    params, e = opt.step_and_cost(feed_forward, params)
    energy.append(e)

    if epoch % 5 == 0:
        print(epoch, energy[-1])
```

Comment: Your code has some omissions so it doesn't directly run, but from looking at it you'll need to use tensor types for your `params`, not tuples. See here for more details: https://docs.pennylane.ai/en/stable/code/api/pennylane.numpy.tensor.html

Comment: Thanks, my code is working